# how to skip a column and multiply the rest?

Tags: python, pandas

i have this table of csv Data:

```
Zeit;Kanal A;Kanal B;Kanal C;Kanal D

(s);(V);(V);(V);(V)

0,00000000;0,00610426;0,00900379;-0,01358198;0,32322060
0,00010000;0,00610426;0,00900379;-0,01648150;-0,04791845
0,00020000;0,00610426;0,00610426;-0,01358198;-0,21319130
0,00030000;-0,00549384;0,00320474;-0,01648150;-0,30307650
0,00040000;0,00610426;0,00320474;-0,01358198;-0,12620560
0,00050000;0,00900379;0,00610426;-0,01358198;0,18984250
0,00060000;0,00610426;0,00320474;-0,01358198;0,45369920
0,00070000;0,00900379;0,00320474;-0,01648150;0,82758520
```

I would like to multiply the columns: "Kanal A" to "Kanal D" with 1000.

How its possible to skip the "Zeit" row and multiply the rest by 1000 ?

So far I have this code:

```
if a['Kanal A'][0] == '(V)':
        df6=pd.read_csv(MU6, sep = ';', skiprows=[1,2],skipcols = [0],dtype=float, decimal=',')
        df6=df6.mul(1000)
```

I would like to use the entire Data Frame to plot it afterwards. For this reason i need to keep the "Zeit" row like it is.

I hope anyone could help me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm A simple solution will be to just multiply them directly.

for example:

```
cols_to_mult = ['Kanal A', 'Kanal B', 'Kanal C', 'Kanal D']
for col in cols_to_mult:
    df6[col] = df6[col]*1000
```

Comment: Looping through a dataframe is usually not the best practice and whenever possible vectorial operations should be preferred. In this case, [the approach with `mul`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455197/16343464) is much faster (and shorter).

Comment: There is no looping over a dataframe. There is looping over list of size 4. mul might work faster but that solution is less readable. What if he changes the order of the columns? Add more columns? Etc etc.. Your solution will require constant workaround and good as an end solution while mine is much more simple and will work better for research requirements

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this input dataframe with MultiIndex columns:

```
     Zeit   Kanal A   Kanal B   Kanal C   Kanal D
      (s)       (V)       (V)       (V)       (V)
0  0.0000  0.006104  0.009004 -0.013582  0.323221
1  0.0001  0.006104  0.009004 -0.016481 -0.047918
2  0.0002  0.006104  0.006104 -0.013582 -0.213191
3  0.0003 -0.005494  0.003205 -0.016481 -0.303077
4  0.0004  0.006104  0.003205 -0.013582 -0.126206
5  0.0005  0.009004  0.006104 -0.013582  0.189842
6  0.0006  0.006104  0.003205 -0.013582  0.453699
7  0.0007  0.009004  0.003205 -0.016481  0.827585
```

(all types are float64)

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df = df.mul([1,1000,1000,1000,1000])  # if large number of columns you can use [1]+[1000]*(df.shape[1]-1) as parameter
```

Alternatively, should Zeit not contain numbers and another operation than multiplication be wanted, you could use:

```
df = (df.set_index(('Zeit', '(s)'))*1000).reset_index()
```

NB. the `.mul(…)` approach would also work with strings as 1*str = str, but not other operations like [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) or [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)